# Determining Similarity of Binary Files

Tags: c#, algorithm, testing

I'm writing unit tests around an HTML to PDF process and have a set of sample input HTML files and a set of PDF representing what the expected result would be.
I'd like to compare these to determine that the process has generated the correct output.

Obviously PDF files have some non-deterministic components in them so I can't do a straight up binary compare. I don't particularly want to delve into parsing the PDF output, so I thought it might be neat to just check how much the files differ by (and have the test pass if they differ by, say, less than 1%).

I can't simply count the differing bytes in the same array location as it seems there can be slight size differences in the output, so things will be offset slightly differently in each file.

So, the question is, is there a tried and tested algorithm for determining how much the general content of 2 large byte arrays differ?

Thanks,

Steve.

Edit:

Attaching an image to illustrate how the files generated are broadly the same...

[image]

Comment: We went through a similar process 2-3 months ago with some PDF forms (with embedded text entry fields), and found it was easier to use Aspose to pull all the fields and their values out and compare *those* than comparing the byte streams, which could change a lot, out of proportion with small changes in a text entry.  I recommend you follow a similar approach.  Comparing the byte streams wasn't as useful as we expected.

Comment: PDF implies compression, so what does a "percentage difference" even mean? It is almost a hash function. You could have a small difference in text and 98% different bytes.

Comment: If I open the files side by side in binary, they are broadly the same. I'll attach an image to illustrate.

Comment: You dont trust you PDF generator utility?

Comment: Not that as such - it's more about ensuring consistent output. The tests will start failing if someone makes a breaking change to the HTML templates for instance. Catching that would be a good thing.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to verify the html in that case before it is converted to pdf?

Comment: That's a fair point. Kind of got a solution now. Just going to write it up because someone else might find it useful.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so I've found a method that seems to work pretty well. It's not necessarily hugely efficient, but each test still runs in about half a second, so it's fine for my purpose. Posting it here in case it helps someone else out.

It basically just sums the bytes in each array and calculates the difference:

```
public static bool IsAnalogousTo(this byte[] left, byte[] right, int tolerance)
{
    long leftSum = 0;

    foreach (var b in left)
    {
        leftSum += b;
    }

    long rightSum = 0;

    foreach (var b in right)
    {
        rightSum += b;
    }

    return Math.Abs(leftSum - rightSum) < left.Length / tolerance;
}
```

My thinking is that the files are ~115k in size - if the sum of all the bytes in files of that size is less than ~15k then that means less than one bit in every ten bytes (the tolerance parameter) is different.

This works well for what I want. For other purposes where more accuracy is required, it would probably better to do it in chunks to ensure regions of the file are similar.

Of course, on a small set of data, this would be useless. It would say that [10, 20, 30, 40] and [0, 0, 0, 100] are the same, but on 115,000 bytes of reasonably structured data such as a PDF, I think this is probably acceptable.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question that was asked: "percentage difference between two files"

Comment: In a roundabout way it does - if there's one bit difference in every ten bytes then that would be that would be a 1.25% difference. With a bit of maths the method could be modified to accept a percentage.

Comment: Not really no.  If one byte goes from 0 to 10, and another byte goes from 10 to 0, then the sum difference is zero, yet the percentage difference is 100% (assuming the file only has two bytes).  This doesn't even approximate a percentage difference between two files.

Comment: This algorithm won't tell you how many bytes changed out of the total number of bytes.  If the sum difference is 10, is that ten bytes changed, one byte changed, or a thousand?  There's no way to tell.

Comment: I agree - hence my comment in the answer about performing this in chunks if you are really worried about accuracy. For my purposes of comparing PDFs, if the sum of all the bytes of a reasonably predictable structured file 115k in size is only a few thousand then it's pretty likely the files are similar.

Comment: If you want to keep this answer, i suggest editing the question so they are more congruent.

Comment: Edited title and expanded explanation in answer.